# Verifying General Solution of Non-Homogeneous Quasilinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Use the method of characteristics to find the general solution of the following PDE
> $$
> e^xu_x + u_y = xu.
> $$
> Show explicitly that your result is indeed a solution of the PDE.

So I believe I have found the general solution as follows:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{-x},$ $\frac{du}{dx} = xue^{-x}$, $\frac{du}{dy} = xu$.

Then, the first eq'n gives $C_1 = y + e^{-x}$. And, the second equation gives $C_2 = \ln{u} + (x+1)e^{-x}$. So, the general solution is given by $\ln{u} + (x+1)e^{-x} = \omega(y + e^{-x})$, where $\omega$ is an arbitrary function. We can rearrange to give an explicit general sol'n:
$$u(x,y) = \exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\}.$$

Now, I'm struggling to, as the question asks, show explicitly that this is a solution. I'm assuming this is wanting me to substitute my solution into the PDE. But, because I have this arbitrary function it doesn't seem to be working.. (?) I can't get my expression for $u(x,y)$ to give me the PDE, i.e., taking partial derivatives and subbing into the PDE I don't get back an expression for $xu$. This is what I have:
\begin{align}
u_x 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [\omega(y + e^{-x})] - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[(x+1)e^{-x}] \right) \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [\ln{u} + (x+1)e^{-x}] - [-xe^{-x}] \right) \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [\ln{u}] + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[(x+1)e^{-x}] + [xe^{-x}] \right) \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \frac{u_x}{u} \\
&= u \cdot \frac{u_x}{u} \\
&= u_x \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
u_y 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} [\omega(y + e^{-x})] - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[(x+1)e^{-x}] \right) \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y} [\ln{u} + (x+1)e^{-x}]  \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y} [\ln{u}]  \\
&=\exp\{\omega(y + e^{-x}) - (x+1)e^{-x}\} \cdot \frac{u_y}{u} \\
&= u \cdot \frac{u_y}{u} \\
&= u_y \\
\end{align}

Is this enough to show that it's a solution? What else can I do with this? Have I missed something?

Comment: Is your second line meant to be your characteristics ODEs, if so it's not right. You also shown that $u_x=u_x$, $u_y=u_y$ in the bottom which is trivially true and doesn't shown anything.

Comment: @FinnPillar Yes, they are supposed to be the characteristic ODEs. In my lectures we were told that for $a(x,y,u)u_x + b(x,y,u)u_y = c(x,y,u)$ the general solution is $v_1(x,y,u) = \omega(v_2(x,y,u))$ for arbitrary $\omega$ and $c_1 = v_1(x,y,u), c_2 = v_2(x,y,u)$ are any solutions of the characteristic ODEs $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{b}{a}, \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{c}{a}, \frac{du}{dy} = \frac{c}{b}$. Is this wrong?

Comment: I don't know about the validity of your version but it is definitely not the one I was taught, nor the one used in most PDE textbooks (standard one is usually Evans PDEs).

Comment: @FinnPillar It's used here: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Introduction_to_Partial_Differential_Equations_(Herman)/01%3A_First_Order_Partial_Differential_Equations/1.03%3A_Quasilinear_Equations-_The_Method_of_Characteristics -- I don't understand why it is giving me the wrong results?

Comment: (1.3.2) from the link you posted is usually the standard characteristic ODEs. Nonetheless, I haven't actually checked your solution. Maybe it's just some error with your computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the third line of the equation $u_x=\ldots$ as
$$
u_x=u\left(-e^{-x}\omega'(\xi)+xe^{-x}\right), \tag{1}
$$
where $\xi:=y+e^{-x}$, and the third line of the equation $u_y=\ldots$ as
$$
u_y=u\, \omega'(\xi). \tag{2}
$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that
$$
e^{x}u_x+u_y=xu.\quad{\square} \tag{3}
$$